# Database and insert data in IBM Worklight?

Tags: database, insert, ibm-mobilefirst

I've successfully set Worklight adapter. But, I don't know how to make database and insert data in IBM Worklight. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already set adapter do so:
In Adapter.xml

```
var query="query sql to create the table";
var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement(query);
function createTable(param) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,
        parameters : [param]
    });
}
```

Declare the procedure in Adapter-impl.js

In APPName.js :

```
createTable();
function createTable(){
    var invocationData={
            adapter : 'AdapterName',
            procedure: 'createTable',
            parameters:[]
        };

         WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,
        {
             onSuccess: function(){
              WL.Logger.debug("ok");

          },
              onFailure: function(){
                  WL.Logger.debug("fail");

              }

        }       
        );  
}
```

Launch the app and, if you set right Worklight adapter, a table will be created (according to the query)